# Insert record in related child object only if size of related object is 0

Tags: apex, batch, schedulebatch

I am trying to insert record in related child object but only if size of related object (Comment__c) is 0. Means there should be no records in relate child object. I have done the implementation but it is inserting duplicate records each time batch is running on child object. Pleas help.

```java
global without sharing class BatchUpdateReasonforSchedulingOutsideSLA implements Database.Batchable<sObject>, Database.Stateful{
    /*
     * Description: Start Method of BatchUpdateReasonforSchedulingOutsideSLA
     */
     global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext bc){
         Set<String> setClosedStatuses = new Set<String>{'Canceled'};
         return Database.getQueryLocator
         ('Select id, name, Reason_For_Scheduling_outside_SLA__c, (select Comment__c from Comments__r) from SVMXC__Service_Order__c where SVMXC__Order_Status__c NOT IN: setClosedStatuses AND Reason_For_Scheduling_outside_SLA__c != NULL');
     }
    /*
     * Description: Execute Method of BatchUpdateReasonforSchedulingOutsideSLA
     */
    global void execute(Database.BatchableContext bc, List<sObject> lstScope){
        List<Comment__c> lstComments = new List<Comment__c>();
        
        for(SVMXC__Service_Order__c objWO : (List<SVMXC__Service_Order__c>)lstScope){
            Comment__c objComments = new Comment__c();
            objComments.Work_Order__c = objWO.Id;
            objComments.Comment__c = 'The reason for scheduling outside the SLA was: '+ objWO.Reason_For_Scheduling_outside_SLA__c;
            lstComments.add(objComments);
        }
        if(!lstComments.isEmpty()){
            insert lstComments;
        }
      
     }
       
     /*
      * Finish Method of BatchUpdateReasonforSchedulingOutsideSLA
      */ 
     global void finish(Database.BatchableContext bc){
         system.debug('inside finish method.');
     }
}
```

Comment: you are not checking anywhere the related object records size and directly inserting new comment record each time. You should first check the list size of comment record before creating a new one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check size of related comment object list before creating new record. if you want to create only one record for each service order. Modify your code as below

```
 for(SVMXC__Service_Order__c objWO : (List<SVMXC__Service_Order__c>)lstScope){
        if(objWO.Comments__r.size() == 0) {
            Comment__c objComments = new Comment__c();
            objComments.Work_Order__c = objWO.Id;
            objComments.Comment__c = 'The reason for scheduling outside the SLA was: '+ objWO.Reason_For_Scheduling_outside_SLA__c;
            lstComments.add(objComments);
          }
        }
```

Comment: Hi Ankur, I am getting this error: A non foreign key field cannot be referenced in a path expression: Comments__r

Comment: size is a method of list class, forgot to add method brackets. Updated the solution above. objWO.Comments__r.size --> objWO.Comments__r.size()

Comment: Hi Ankur.. this resolved the issue. Thank you so much. Just wanted to check if we can query for those records only for which Comments__r.size() == 0 in start method to reduce the size of batch.Is there any possibility for that?

Comment: Yes, You can query [SELECT Id FROM SVMXC__Service_Order__c WHERE Id NOT IN (SELECT SVMXC__Service_Order__c FROM Comment__C). Please put the relationship fields name correctly. It will give you all the service orders with zero comment records attached.